# Is there a way to store data values from firestore into an array?

Tags: java, android, arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get data in a two specific field in each document where one field is a integer and the other is a string. I want each field to be stored in an array separately.

```
 db.collection("Activity")
                .whereEqualTo("plan_id", plan_id)
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            List<Long> progressList = new ArrayList<>();
                            List<String> titleList = new ArrayList<>();
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.get("progress"));

                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });
```

I've tried

```
int[] prog = (int[]) document.get("progress");
String[] title = (String[]) document.get("title");
```

but no luck...

Comment: Do you want to store those data values into `Array` or `List`? Because I saw there were 2 declarations of `List` for *progress* and *title*, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with Firestore, but it seems that the `QueryDocumentSnapshot` is similar to `Map<String, Object>`. Following code snippet shows how to store those values into `List` as declared in your code - progressList and titleList, respectively.

```
List<int> progressList = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> titleList = new ArrayList<>();
for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
    progressList.add(Integer.valueOf(document.get("progress").toString()));
    titleList.add(document.get("title").toString());
}
```

And if you still want to use `Array` to store values, you can use API `ArrayList.toArray()` as follows:

```
int[] prog = new int[progressList.size()];
prog = progressList.toArray(prog);

String[] title = new String[titleList.size()];
title = titleList.toArray(title);
```